# Get HTML5 validation to work with onclick?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I have a form for name, company, email, and phone number, and using required it makes sure that the form has something filled in for each input. What I am trying to do is have it download a file to the computer of the visitors who fill out the form, and have this code handling the download:

HTML:

```
<input type="submit" id="submitbutton" onclick="download()">
```

JS:

```
function download(){
    window.open('the_file.zip');
}
```

However, adding the onclick is causing the form to bypass validation and it will submit and download with nothing needing to be filled out. What can I do here to make sure the HTML5 validation works?

Comment: try `e.preventDefault();` in your download function

Comment: @StevoPerisic The default on a submit button is to validate the form fields and send them somewhere, though. Pretty sure Chipe still wants that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would listen for the submit rather than the click event.

Using jQuery:

```
$('form').submit(function(event){
    alert('form was submitted!');
    // window.open('the_file.zip');
    // event.preventDefault();

    // ... do something else ...

    // $(this).submit();
});
```

Then you could also prevent the default action of submit `event.preventDefault();` before if you wanted to do something before you actually submitted the form.

Comment: I dont see any jQuery tag in this question

Comment: "I don't see a..." you mean. 

I am happy to take time and provide suggestions to this problem. My solution is pretty vanilla - and if @Chipe is not in fact using jQuery, just by reading my idea could trigger a solution that could be written out in plain old javascript.

You have not provided any useful information to this post other than to criticize my response. It's a waste of everyone's time.

Comment: I doubt, that comment got up-voted. I only mentioned that jquery tag is missing because I assumed that the answer should be provided using vanilla js. In some cases, you can't always rely to jquery, I though that this could be one of those cases. Nothing weird about that, no need to get angry over it.

Comment: Just added the jquery CDN and the window.open part of this function and thats all I needed! Thanks!

Comment: form.submit = function() {
    //I rock... Z28
    window.open('the_file.zip');
    return; //return whatever you want...
}

Answer (score 0):

What you should really do is, instead of an `onclick` event, set the `form` `action` attribute to a server page that validates the form, then, if the form is valid, redirects the user to `the_file.zip`.

Even by doing something like `event.preventDefault()`, I'm pretty sure you're also going to prevent the form values from being processed by anything (they'll just sit their in their respective input fields and a new window will open with the file to download).