# html5 validation and JS

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

On confirm the function is called but it skips the HTML5 validation and just redirects.
As of now the page is static, no other validation is there.

```
<label> Email :</label>
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="new_email"
       placeholder="Enter Email" required autofocus
       autocomplete="off" style="width:300px;"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function submitdetails() {
        if(confirm("Do you want to proceed")  == true) {
            document.write("Creating your Account, please wait...");
            setTimeout('window.location = "confirm.html";',5000);
        } else {
            document.write("Redirecting to home page, please wait...");
            setTimeout('window.location = "new_fss.html";',5000);
        }
    }
</script>
```

HTML :

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:100px;margin-left:50px;" onclick="submitdetails();">Submit</button>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you have that 5 second delay in there?

Comment: Not sure if Im missing something but where's the HTML5 validation?

Comment: does it effects anything?

Comment: @Richlewis   <label> Email :</label> <input type="email" class="form-control"        id="new_email" placeholder="Enter Email" required autofocus autocomplete="off" style="width:300px;"/>

Comment: @user3211681: Please don't use excessive whitespace in your code, or citation blocks for your question. It makes the question more difficult to read.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get HTML5 validation to work with onclick?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24919337/get-html5-validation-to-work-with-onclick)

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr: Don't just add HTML to a question.

Comment: @Cerbrus Its the HTML from his comment, it adds context. But hey, its all cool, I'm not getting in a rollback war over this.

Comment: @Cerbrus No stress. It happens to the best of us.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the HTML5 isn't kicking in is because your javascript is being run *before* the validation can trigger.

Your `onclick` action is firing, which runs the javascript, which redirects the user.

Comment: Look at the duplicate question, and probably rethink exactly what you are trying to achieve. Redirecting to "`confirm.html`" is not the same as submitting a form.

Comment: @user3211681 If the answer solves your question, its helped to let future visitors know by accepting it using the tick. Upvoting also lets users know which questions and answers are good. Remember, only *your involvement* makes StackOverflow work!